How to properly use button.when_pressed function from gpiozero module?
hi i am new with raspberry pi and i am using the gpiozero library.... Can someone tell me why you have to make a loop after button.when_pressed? For example :
button.when_pressed = onButtonPressed 
    while True: time.sleep(1)`

I tried this and the when_pressed function did not work:
def loop():
#Button detect
    button.when_pressed = onButtonPressed

